# Find center of square that a point is in

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry-surface

Currently in my program I defined a square in a square grid by its upper left corner. I want to change the definition so a square is defined by it's center. However, the X and Y values of a square have to be round numbers.

A method for finding the upper left corner of a square a point is in:

```
public Vector2 InSquare(Vector2 vector)
{
    int x = (int)vector.X, y = (int)vector.Y;//floor of vector coordinates
    x -= x % SquareSize;
    y -= y % SquareSize;
    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

SquareSize is a property of type int (it can be and odd number). Vector2 is the XNA vector with float X and Y properites. SquareSize is the length of the square's edge.

How can I change the definition of a square to it's center point but still have the centers be with round coordinates?

(I didn't tag this question as XNA because it does not require XNA experience to understand)

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

What I tried to do is to represent the level in a game with a uniform square grid. a square on the grid was defined by it's upper left corner. However, since I know which squares are blocked by iterating over the level's texture, applying a matrix to each point, and then blocking the square the point is in, having the squares be defined by their upper left corner meant each blocked square was slightly off to the left from where it was supposed to be. Having each square be defined by their center point meant having each blocked square closer to where the obstacle is on the map.

I hope this explains the problem better.

Thanks @potato for his/hers answer. My current method:

```
    public Vector2 InSquare(Vector2 vector)
    {
        float x = vector.X, y = vector.Y;//floor of vector coordinates
        x -= x % SquareSize - (SquareSize / 2);
        y -= y % SquareSize - (SquareSize / 2);
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }
```

I've changed Square size to float.

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to achieve, can you please put some effort in reformulating the question?

Comment: A Point can only be integers, but PointF can be floating point numbers.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry for having written such a poor question. I wrote it while sleepy and stressed, and not going to waste anyone's time by doing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of the square is `SquareSize`, half of `SquareSize` is the exact middle.

```
public Vector2 InSquare(Vector2 vector)
{
   int x = (int)vector.X, y = (int)vector.Y;//floor of vector coordinates
   x -= x % SquareSize - (SquareSize / 2);
   y -= y % SquareSize - (SquareSize / 2);
   return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

However if `SquareSize` is an odd number, you will not be able to store the exact center of the square as an integer. The result of `SquareSize / 2` will be 0.5 less than the real center.

(e.g. 9 / 2 = 4)

If you need the coordinates precise, consider using float variables instead of integers, or keep the coordinates pointing at the corner of the square.

**EDIT:**
The rounded down numbers you get are still good enough to easily calculate the location of all sides of the square:

```
int left    =  x - (SquareSize / 2);
int top     =  y - (SquareSize / 2);
int right   =  left + SquareSize;
int bottom  =  top + SquareSize;
```

Comment: I've adapted your solution, and changed SquareSize to int. Memory is not my current problem anyway. Thank you!